# Git merge two branches and bring both branches to same level

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches master and dev. we usually work on dev branch and then after few days do

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

this brings all the changes of dev into master.
but the issue we have is that our dev branches doesnt have changes that occur in master. so today i did

```
git checkout dev 
git merge master
```

after that i did some more work and commit it on dev branch and someone else changed the master branch as well. Now i want to push all my changes to master and ring master and dev at the same level
what should i do ?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) the dev branch on master?

```
git rebase master dev
```

and then merge (fast-forward) master to dev

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```